# How to disable a submit button in redux form for the second time after the form is submitted for the first time?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm a beginner to react-redux and I want to disable my submit button after a first successful submit..The button is disabled and works perfect on its first submit but the second time it doesn't get disabled. Is there a solution for this?
And the following is my code..

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Field,
  reduxForm,
  getFormValues,
  formValueSelector,
  reset,
  formValues,
  invalid
} from "redux-form";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { regionActions } from "./ducks/index";
import { Row, Col, ButtonToolbar, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { InputField } from "./../../components/controls/Fields";
import "./regionManagement.scss";
//import { handleInputChange } from "react-select/src/utils";

const validate = values => {
  const errors = {};
  // const fieldVal = ["regionName", "code", "description"];
  const fieldVal = ["regionName"];

  fieldVal.forEach(fieldVal => {
    if (!values[fieldVal]) {
      errors[fieldVal] = "Region Name is Required";
    }
  });
  return errors;
};

class RegionForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errors: false
    };
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.mode && this.props.mode != prevProps.mode) {
      //when changing the mode from edit to add
      if (this.props.mode == "add") {
        this.props.initialize({
          selectedRegion: null,
          regionName: null,
          code: null,
          description: null
        });
      }
    }

    if (
      this.props.selectedRegion &&
      this.props.selectedRegion != prevProps.selectedRegion
    ) {
      this.props.initialize({
        selectedRegion: this.props.selectedRegion && this.props.selectedRegion,
        regionName: this.props.selectedRegion && this.props.selectedRegion.name,
        code: this.props.selectedRegion && this.props.selectedRegion.code,
        description:
          this.props.selectedRegion && this.props.selectedRegion.description
      });
      this.setState({ selectedRegion: this.props.selectedRegion });
    }
    if (this.props.region.clearFields == true) {
      this.props.reset(); // reset() comes as a prop with redux-form
      //this.props.invalid();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {
      handleSubmit,
      onSubmit,
      invalid,
      submitting,
      pristine
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <h5>{this.props.title}</h5>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Name</label>
            <span style={{ color: "red" }}> *</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Field
              type="text"
              className="form-control mb-2"
              name="regionName"
              component={InputField}
              disabled={this.props.fieldDisabled}
            />
          </div>
          {/* {this.props.mode == "add" ? ( */}
          <>
            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Code</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Field
                type="text"
                className="form-control mb-2"
                name="code"
                component={InputField}
                disabled={this.props.fieldDisabled}
              />
            </div>

            <div className="form-group">
              <label>Description</label>
            </div>
            <div>
              <Field
                type="text"
                className="form-control mb-2"
                name="description"
                component={InputField}
                disabled={this.props.fieldDisabled}
              />
            </div>
          </>

          <ButtonToolbar>
            <Button
              as="input"
              type="submit"
              name="formBtn"
              value={this.props.button}
              className="button"
              disabled={this.props.mode == "edit" ? pristine : invalid}
            />
          </ButtonToolbar>
        </form>
      </>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    region: state.Regions,
    fieldValues: getFormValues("region_form")(state)
  };
}

export default withRouter(
  reduxForm({
    form: "region_form",
    validate
    // enableReinitialize: true
  })(connect(mapStateToProps, regionActions)(RegionForm))
);
```

I have 3 modes in my redux form and they are "add", "edit", and "view".. During the "add" mode, the submit button should not be enabled until the regionName is filled out.because it's  a mandatory field. This happens for the very first time...and after the form get reset, the button is not disabled even when the regionName is not given.  Please help me to sort this out.

I think the button disable feature should be embedded to componentDidUpdate() along with initialize... How can I do that? If the mode is "add" then it should be disable={invalid} and if "edit" , it should be disable={pristine}... How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

in case if you are using redux-form there's a hack actually. whenever the form submission succeeds it'll return a boolean submitSucceeded as true. you can intercept it from componentWillReceiveProps().

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      errors: false,
      disableSubmit: false,
    };
  }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 if (nextProps && nextProps.submitSucceeded) {
   this.setState(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    disableSubmit: true,
 }
}
```

it'll only be set to true once whenever the submission succeeds. so, you'll need a state variable as a persistent source, in our case, disableSubmit.